# Having to cast to id to invoke isKindOfClass

Tags: objective-c

In the following code

```
id<SwiftProtocol> anotherInstanceAsProtocol = [[SomeObjectiveCClassImplementingOBJCSwiftProtocol alloc] init];
[anotherInstanceAsProtocol isKindOfClass:[SomeObjectiveCClassImplementingOBJCSwiftProtocol class]];
```

I get the warning "No known instance method for selector 'isKindOfClass:'"

If I modify the last line to

```
[(id)anotherInstanceAsProtocol isKindOfClass:[SomeObjectiveCClassImplementingOBJCSwiftProtocol class]]
```

It runs perfectly.

It also works if I assign to `NSObject<SwiftProtocol>` instead of `id<SwiftProtocol>`, but I think neither should be necessary.

Why is this cast necessary?

Comment: Most likely the protocol does not extend protocol `NSObject`?

Comment: But that would also be the case for id, no?

Comment: `id` means that you don't want any type checking, you can call anything on `id`. `id<protocol>` is a different thing. To call `isKindOfClass` you need an object that conforms to protocol [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject?language=objc). All Obj-C protocols should inherit from that protocol exactly for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `SwiftProtocol` does not inherit from [NSObject(Protocol)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject?language=objc) therefore the Obj-C compiler does not know that there is a method called `isKindOfClass:`.

Using `id` basically means you don't want any type checking at compilation time. The real fix should be to make the protocol extend `NSObjectProtocol`, making sure that all instances conforming to it are normal Obj-C objects.

Note that the history of Objective-C is complicated and not all Objective-C objects have to inherit from `NSObject` and have `isKindOfClass:` available.

Comment: Brilliant, that's super clear and makes sense. Thanks.